# NoMethodError in Pins#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im making a blog website and im struggling with adding a comment section. I installed the commontator gem and followed the steps.  I have `acts_as_commontator` in my user model. `acts_as_commontable` in my pins model. `<%= commontator_thread(@commontable) %>` in my pins show.

I'm getting a NoMethodError. I dont understand why it is not understanding my method call when I have the method in my model.

My Pin show.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading center">
     <%= image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium) %>
    </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <p><%= @pin.description %></p>
      <p><strong><%= @pin.user.name if @pin.user %></strong></p>

      <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(@pin) %>
      <% end %>
     </div>
    </div>
    <%= commontator_thread(@commontable) %>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

My Models Pin.erb

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb =>          "100x100>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg",    "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
validates :image, presence: true
acts_as_commontable
end
```

My Models User.erb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 has_many :pins

 validates :name, presence: true
acts_as_commontator
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the relevant portions of the stacktrace, and the code around the area indicated therein...

Comment: did you add `commontator_thread_show(commontable)` in your controller file?

Comment: Don't post (links to) pictures of code. Type them. Don't be lazy. Don't expect other people to do your part.

Comment: Ive tried adding commontator_thread_show(commontable) to my application controller or my Pins controller and I end up with routing errors

Comment: Can you try using `<%= commontator_thread(@pin) %> ` instead of `commontator_thread_show(commontable)` ? If that doesn't work, then please try referring to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342512/undefined-local-variable-or-method-error-when-using-commontator-gem-for-commen

Answer (score 0):

the most common issue is that your @commontable variable is nil and then you get NoMethodError which expect to get an :id.

check if @commontable is not nil also try to change @commontable with your @pin that looks fine because he not throwing any error on edit path.